# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio -> Invalid column name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am new to SQL Server. While working with datasets, I am having issues while trying to join them as I am getting an invalid column. I don't know why. I tried it white another dataset and it worked fine but while working with another one, I am getting this issue. I am attaching both pictures.
[image]

Any assistance will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: are you sure that you have a column of that table, is any spelling mistake ?

Comment: I didn't see any spelling mistake. In the 2nd picture, I did it for another table. But in the 1st one, I don't know why they are showing the error

Comment: why are you use first create and in just next statement alter. No issue, you just select the alter portion of your view and run only that by f5 (check that error still comes). Then just run the select query of your views in another window by ctrl+n and check what you get.

Comment: I only selected the alter portion to run and check, not everything. After that the error came. It didn't let me alter as it kept saying invalid column name

Comment: now just select the select query in another window

Comment: nope it's not working

Comment: just select a table and press alt+f1 will show you the table description and columns list, then check with copy-paste the column name in select query

Comment: Hi Tom, is it possible to replace the phone-photos with examples of what did you try and what was the errors? (It is really hard to see the error message and select statement). Another point: please update the question with the creation statement, An third: are you on right database? Check the drop down list in the left upper corner - does it point to the right server?

Comment: `GO` in between the `CREATE` and `ALTER`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include properly-formatted text for both your sql and your errors, rather than your screenshots. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Answer (score 0):

The red squiggly line under "Team_Batting" indicates that this is definitely NOT a field in  your "Team" table.

Long shot... Is it possible that your field has a space between Team and Batting?  If so try referring to this field as [Team Batting] in square brackets.